# Was (Smith)Bane communicating with Smith?

Tags: the-matrix

My [Answer to another question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/80387/25784) got me thinking about whether or not (Smith)Bane was communicating with the Agent Smith Program inside the Matrix.

Is it possible that (Smith)Bane is just a copy of the program that needed to communicate with the Smith Program for instruction intermittently?

Comment: I don't recall any instance where the Smith inside the Matrix used information gleaned from Smith/Bane.

Comment: Well, if Neo's mind was able to send signals to emulate himself in the Matrix, even unplugged, I wouldn't doubt it could be possible in Bane/Smith's case to communicate with the Matrix... Though it never happened

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know that the first thing that comes to mind is Neo's encounter with the Sentinel, then comes the fact that he exists inside the train station on [Mobil Ave](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Mobil_Avenue).

let's look at these for a minute and decide later whether Smith could communicate in the same fashion as these two instances.

Let's first take a look at the realms that we know to exist given the information in the 3 movies

1. The Matrix
2. The Train Station ([Mobil Ave](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Mobil_Avenue).)
3. The Machine World
4. The Real World

We know that [Mobil ave.](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Mobil_Avenue) exists as a gateway between the Machine World and the Matrix because the Programs there are being carted to a place where they will be safe from Smith and the Destruction of the Matrix, some even say that the programs hide in the Train Station during the reboot of the Matrix so this is a separate realm from the Matrix and not dependent on it for survival.

In the Real world, real machines are after the Humans that have been set free from the Matrix.  These machines must have a wireless link to the machine world.

let's map out a little something here quickly

- Machine World

  - Servers
  - Sentinels
  - Machines
- The Train Station

  - a Port on a server between the Matrix and the "Server"(Machine World)
  - or a storage device connected to the Machine world with a program that downloads to the Matrix and the Machine World based on a set of rules defined by the [The Trainman](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/The_Trainman) Program
- The Matrix

  - The Signal from this program must be broadcast via wireless signals for some reason as the Humans (unplugged) in the real world are able to hack into the signal to reintroduce what I call their "program" to the Matrix and bring it back

The Train Station, The Matrix, Sentinels and other machines are all connected to the Machine World in some fashion or another.

I also assume that the Matrix is not the only place in the Machine world where there are programs.

When the Sentinel finds them Neo sends out his program to shut down the Sentinel, instead of his program returning to his body, a connection is made to the Machine world, seeing as how there is no place for Neo's "program" in the Machine world it is sent to a type of purgatory for exiled programs that don't quite fit anywhere anymore, [The Train Station](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Mobil_Avenue). But Neo is still connected by Wireless signal, had the machines been ready for him they could have assimilated his code this way before he was sent to [The Train Station](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Mobil_Avenue).  Neo couldn't leave because he didn't understand the laws or ideas behind the place where he was, it was a brand new Matrix with one way out.

We also know that there is only one way into [The Train Station](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Mobil_Avenue) this lends itself to the fact that everyone is safe there, safe from The Matrix, from the Program Smith, and safe from Deletion.

With this information it is possible that the Program Smith could have been able to communicate with (Smith)Bane in a similar manner if he was able to find a way to broadcast the signal close enough to (Smith)Bane, Theoretically.

Comment: For the record, Smith/Bane was easily in broadcast range of the Matrix had he wanted to communicate with Smith/Smith before triggering the EMP. There's no special reason to assume that he did though.